# How to change the column order according to the category list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, heatmap

I have a dataframe `df` and the column `cats` is categorical, as:

```
> df['cats'] = pd.Categorical(df['cats'], categories=['A+', 'A', 'B+', 'B', 'C', '-'], ordered=True)
```

From `df` I got a `df1` like the following table:

|  | groups | cats | value_name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | group1 | - | 0.04 | ... |
| 1 | group1 | A | 0.02 | ... |
| 2 | group1 | A+ | 0.12 | ... |
| 3 | group1 | B | 0.00 | ... |
| 4 | group1 | B+ | 0.25 | ... |
| 5 | group2 | - | 0.00 | ... |
| 6 | group2 | A | 0.05 | ... |
| 7 | group2 | A+ | 0.30 | ... |
| 8 | group2 | B | 0.09 | ... |
| 9 | group2 | B+ | 0.04 | ... |
| 10 | group3 | - | 0.13 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Then I used `df.pivot()` and changed the `MultiIndex` columns to simple columns by renaming them:

```
> df2 = df1.iloc[:,0:2].set_index('groups').pivot(columns='value_name')
> df2.columns = df2.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

The resulting dataframe is:

| cats | - | A | A+ | B | B+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| groups |  |  |  |  |  |
| group1 | 0.04 | 0.02 | 0.12 | 0.00 | 0.25 |
| group2 | 0.00 | 0.05 | 0.30 | 0.09 | 0.04 |
| group3 | 0.13 | 0.06 | 0.09 | 0.20 | 0.00 |

This is the target dataframe:

| cats | A+ | A | B+ | B | - |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| groups |  |  |  |  |  |
| group1 | 0.12 | 0.02 | 0.25 | 0.00 | 0.04 |
| group2 | 0.30 | 0.05 | 0.04 | 0.09 | 0.00 |
| group3 | 0.09 | 0.06 | 0.00 | 0.20 | 0.13 |

My target dataframe should have ordered columns, because I need it later in plots and the columns will be x-axis. The problem is that the `cats` values may not always be complete as the category I defined before. In this case, `'C'` is missing in `df1`. I don't want to change the order by hand (slicing dataframes and concatenate them again) because I will generate many similar `df`s in loops and the `cats` values are not the same.

**Follow-up question:**

In the process, I had to convert the `category` to `string` or `int` in order to do some calculations, and convert back to `category`. Sometimes, however, `df['cats'] = pd.Categorical(df['cats'], categories=cats_list, ordered=True)` can't replace the `cats` values as it supposed to.

There is another `cats`, which is a list of numbers. When I convert it back to `category`, some `cats` values (not all), that correspond to `NaN` or `0` from the calculated columns, become `NaN`. (It doesn't matter if it has long format or wide format. I'll just use the wide format here as an example.)

Before:

| cats | 0 | 10 | 20 | 50 | 100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| groups |  |  |  |  |  |
| group1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| group2 |  |  |  |  |  |

After:

| cats | 0 | 10 | 20 | 50 | NaN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| groups |  |  |  |  |  |
| group1 |  |  |  |  |  |
| group2 |  |  |  |  |  |

Does anyone know what might cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) seems incorrect, you should fix the parameters and combine with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) on `axis=1`:

```
df2 = (df
 .pivot(index='groups', columns='cats', values='value_name')
 .sort_index(axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
cats      A+     A    B+     B     -
groups                              
group1  0.12  0.02  0.25  0.00  0.04
group2  0.30  0.05  0.04  0.09  0.00
group3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.13
```

You can check that you have an ordered CategoricalIndex as column:

```
df2.columns
CategoricalIndex(['A+', 'A', 'B+', 'B', '-'],
                 categories=['A+', 'A', 'B+', 'B', 'C', '-'],
                 ordered=True, dtype='category', name='cats')
```

Comment: Sorry, my original script has lots of referable variable names for loops, I didn't copy everything correctly. The pivot function is edited now. 
`sort_index` works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For me working [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) for correct ordering columns:

```
df['cats'] = pd.Categorical(df['cats'], 
                            categories=['A+', 'A', 'B+', 'B', 'C', '-'], 
                            ordered=True)

df2 = df.pivot('groups','cats','value_name').sort_index(axis=1)
print (df2)
cats      A+     A    B+     B     -
groups                              
group1  0.12  0.02  0.25  0.00  0.04
group2  0.30  0.05  0.04  0.09  0.00
group3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  0.13
```

Comment: Thank you! If I lose the categorical `dtype`, sometimes I have trouble converting it back (see my follow-up question).